# Object reference is required error (array of objects)

Tags: c#

Picture of code: http://prntscr.com/gm7cqv

I'm making a program that calculates the maximum and average speed of a car from array of objects, and I'm getting this problem and am not sure how to fix it:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.niz'   G6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c

Comment: Have you even *tried* to search for this error? There are thousands of questions like this, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264308/c-sharp-error-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method
Apart from this don´t paste images of your code, because it´s impossible to search for keywords in your code within a search-engine. Intead post your actual code diretly to the question, but just the *relevant* code, not your entire code-base.

Comment: You should include the code in the question, not make a picture if it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your array static

```
static Auto[] niz = new Auto[3];
```

Or you have to create an instance of the class that contains the array (notice method `metoda` is not static then)

```
rezultat = new Program().metoda();

public string metoda() {...
```

Comment: Yes, @Aominè, I was just adding that, I agree with you