# why does my program return "CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Question3.primechec(BigInteger)'"?

Tags: c#

im new to C# and ive been trying to solve project euler question number 3 and got the following error:
i understand i need to decler a new BigInt before i use it, but i just cant figure out the syntax. would love to get some help!

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
namespace primes
{
    class Question3
    {
       static void Main()
       {
        BigInteger Memash = 600851475143 ;
        for(BigInteger i = 100 ; i <= Memash ; i++)
            {
                if(primechec(i))
                    {
                        Console.Write("this number is prime: " + i);
                        if(Memash % i == 0)
                        {
                            Console.Write(i);
                        }
                    }
            }
       } 

       public bool primechec(BigInteger Naor)
       {
        for(int j = 2 ; j <= Naor ; j++)
        {
            if(Naor % j == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please follow sensible naming conventions. There's no good reason not to. `primes` should be `Primes`, `Memash` should be `memash`, `primechec` should be `PrimeCheck` and `Naor` should be `naor`. You should [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264308/c-sharp-error-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Main` method is `static`, so it can't call instance methods in the same class. You need to declare `primechec` static as well, so you're calling a `static` method from a `static` method.

Comment: so how can i fix it.
adding static to both would help?

Comment: @Se1234 "You need to declare primechec static as well"

Comment: @Se1234, there's only two sentences in my answer and it seems that you didn't bother to read the second one.

Comment: @user18387401 why do you think i didnt bother to read it?
i did and it really helped. i just forgot to reply back because i continued the project euler im sorry.
it really helped thank you

Comment: @Se1234, the reason I thought that you didn't bother to read that second sentence is because you proceeded to ask whether it would help to do what that sentence explicitly instructs you to do. It seems an odd question to ask if you've already read the answer. Anyway, if this answer resolved your issue, please accept it by clicking the check/tick mark next to it. That will let people see that your question has been answered and you need no more help without having to open the question and read a comment on the answer.